# Restore corrupted USB drive

Tags: partitioning

I get read/write error when trying to create a new partitioning table on a USB drive.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
mke2fs 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
Warning: could not erase sector 2: Input/output error
Creating filesystem with 31258624 4k blocks and 7815168 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 8eac3af0-c5a7-4f09-ba50-8938c382058e
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Warning: could not read block 0: Input/output error
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Input/output error
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (131072 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:   0/954
```

It stalls after that. Any ideas?

I also tried:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc status=progress
dd: writing to '/dev/sdc': Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00130756 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

as well as

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdc           
e2fsck 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
e2fsck: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

as well as

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc
mke2fs 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
Creating filesystem with 31258624 4k blocks and 7815168 inodes
Filesystem UUID: ada49f78-45f9-49da-b2ef-d76383582ffd
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

I tried sudo e2fsck -b xxxx  where xxxx is a block listed above but it returns the same output all the time:

```
e2fsck 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
e2fsck: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I don't need to restore any data from this drive just want to make it usable again. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following link may help you analyze the problem, and let us hope, solve it.

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

use mkfs to format partitions
use fdisk or parted to create partition table and partitions

Comment: There is no partition and no partitioning table currently on the USB

Comment: use fdisk to create a table

Comment: @cmak.fr Could you elaborate? `fdisk` is not the easiest tool to use. Please [edit] your answer to add details, do not post them in comments.

Comment: you can use the grafical partitionning tool gparted > apt-get install gparted.
its very easy to use